# How to overlay text with a line to create flip-clock style

Tags: android, layout, shapes

I need to create a flip clock styled counter, that should look like this:

[image]

So basically I need a black shape with white text that is striked through by a black line. Creating the black background shape is no problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dp"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#000000"
    android:startColor="#828282" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:topRightRadius="4dp" />
```

Now I wonder how I can create the line that is on top of the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create transparent layout, that overlays your shape and then draw your line on it

Comment: How can I overlay the text/shape with another layout? Is there a special layout for overlays?

Comment: RelativeLayout or MergeLayout